# Планировщик задач на день

Tags: c#, классы, планировщик-задач

Нужно описание классов для "Планировщика задач на день". Примерное понятие задачи.

Comment: А в чем вопрос-то?

Comment: Вопрос в следующем: сделайте мне описание классов :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[TaskScheduler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.threading.tasks.taskscheduler.aspx)

> Представляет объект, обрабатывающий низкоуровневую постановку задач в очередь на потоки.
>
> Дополнительные сведения и примеры кода см. в разделе [Планировщики заданий](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/dd997402.aspx).